# How to add Predefined Text in Facebook App Invite Dialog? (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using AppInviteDialog to send invitation to facebook friends,I want to attach Text with my feed and then it should share on friends wall.But as per my research App invite dialog not support this.I want to do this without create custom story.is it possible?

**My Requirements :**

- Fetch all facebook friends list with multiple selection.(I can use me/taggable_friends for this.
- I can send Text message with image to selected friends only.

I can not use Sharedialog for this as it will also display on my wall which is wrong.

I am using Facebook 4+ SDK.

Any one please suggest how to achieve this.

Here is the attached screenshot for the same.

[image])

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“(I can use me/taggable_friends for this)”_ – no, you can not. That endpoint is for tagging people in OG stories _only_, and you are not allowed to abuse it for anything else. And if you use invites, the user has to write the message they want to send, your app is not allowed to specify it for them. And normal wall posts are something completely different than invites.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks so much for the clarification,appreciated.But my goal is to fetch full list of friends,select multiple friends,then send text or image to selected friends's wall.This was working with old sdk but after updating application this is not working any more.

Comment: @CBroe In my case I need full list of friends not only app user as per new update of SDK. can you give me some suggestion regarding my requirements,is it feasible or not?

Comment: You can not post to other people’s walls via API either. What options you have for inviting people are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite

Comment: @CBroe so there is no option left to share text or image to friend? I just want to share text feed to some of my friends. is there any alternative then  please let me know.

Comment: You can let your users send them a link, and that link can have title, description and thumbnail set via OG meta tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94079/discussion-between-priyank-bhojak-and-cbroe).

Comment: I don’t see much else that needs discussion.

Comment: @CBroe Ok thanks for your time. Let me see how i can do.

Answer (score 1):

As per the research there is no way to add predefined text in invite dialog.but I found work around to share message with multiple friends with use of share intent.I am sharing my answer here hope it will be helpful for someone.

```
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                shareIntent
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                                "Text that you want to share"));
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
                try {
                    startActivity(shareIntent);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(contextAct, "Please Install Facebook Messenger App", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

This is working fine if facebook massager app is installed.User can select multiple friends and share message to them with use of it.if application is not installed in phone then user need to download facebook massager app to share message.